# Unidirectional one to many association in Hibernate / spring-data-jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to `Hibernate` / `spring-data-jpa` and I'm trying to implement an unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship.

My parent class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

And my child class:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Now I want to persist a new child via

```
Child newChild = new Child();
newChild.setName("child_1");

this.parentService.findParentByParentId(1).getChildren().add(newChild);
this.childService.saveChild(newChild);
```

but when I have a look into my database, the foreign key in **child table** is not set:

```
-----------------------------------------
|  id |    name       |    parent_id    |
-----------------------------------------
|  1  |    child_1    |    NULL         |
-----------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions about what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the mapping and there's nothing wrong with it. I've even compared with some [code](https://github.com/augusto/jpa-workshop/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ig/training/hibernate/domainmodel/onetomany) I use to run JPA workshops and yours should work.

I would bet that the problem is the place where you start the transaction. The transaction should start in the method that executes the code

```
Child newChild = new Child();
newChild.setName("child_1");

this.parentService.findParentByParentId(1).getChildren().add(newChild);
this.childService.saveChild(newChild);
```

Otherwise JPA's unit of work won't see that you've added a child in the parent.

I **strongly** suggest you to read the section in the spring docs that explains the [declarative transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-explained), otherwise know that you'll spend days in despair trying to figure out why it doesn't work.